# Hiding Rows if Cell in a Column Contains Certain Text or Autofiltering a Single Field with 4 Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with columns A through M, containing a table including all rows and columns. If, in column E, a cell contains the string(s) "Drive", "Inactivity", or "Halt" then I want the row to be hidden. If, in column E, a cell does *not* contain the string "UF_", then I want it to be hidden.

I have tried several things and have looked in many places. Here is some code that I have tried:

Try 1 (takes wayyyy to long):

```
With ActiveSheet
loopct = 2

While loopct < count1
    DoEvents
    Application.StatusBar = "Making Table " & loopct
    txtrmv1 = "Drive"
    txtrmv2 = "Inactivity"
    txtrmv3 = "Halt"
    txtkp = "UF_"

    celltxt = .Range("E" & loopct).Value

    If InStr(1, celltxt, txtrmv1, vbTextCompare) Then
        .Range("E" & loopct).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    If InStr(1, celltxt, txtrmv2, vbTextCompare) Then
        .Range("E" & loopct).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    If InStr(1, celltxt, txtrmv3, vbTextCompare) Then
        .Range("E" & loopct).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    If InStr(1, celltxt, txtkp, vbTextCompare) Then
        .Range("E" & loopct).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        .Range("E" & loopct).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    loopct = loopct + 1
Wend

End With
```

Try 2 (runs but accomplishes nothing):

```
Private Sub HideDrive(ByVal count1 As Long)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        Set rng = .Range("E2:E" & CStr(count1))

        Set aCell = rng.Find(What:="Drive", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell
            Do
                aCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Set aCell = rng.FindNext(After:=aCell)

            Loop While aCell Is Nothing And aCell.Address <> bCell
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Here is what I was using when I only had one criteria to check for (obviously my sitation has changed):

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tblnm).Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:= "=*UF_*"
```

What can I do to accomplish what I want? I haven't been able to get autofilter to work with more than two criteria. Please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't debug and run the other answer given, so I continued working and solved it myself.

Instead of trying to hide each word I didn't want all together, I hid them individually and then called a hidden row deleting function each time.

```
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(DataArea1), , xlYes).Name = _
            tblnm

        'insert if statement here to change filters based upon area
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tblnm).Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=*UF_*"

        Call RhidRow2(count4)

        ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tblnm).Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>*Drive*"

        Call RhidRow2(count4)

        ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tblnm).Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>*Inactivity*"

        Call RhidRow2(count4)

        ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tblnm).Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>*Halt*"

        Call RhidRow2(count4)

        ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tblnm).Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>#VALUE!"

        Call RhidRow2(count4)
```

Here is the hidden row deleter:

```
Private Sub RhidRow2(ByVal count4 As Long)
    Dim count1 As Long 'counters to be used
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngVis As Range
    Dim rngDel As Range
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngVis = ws.Range("A2:A" & count4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rngVis Is Nothing Then
        ws.Range("Z1").Value = 1
    Else

        For count1 = count4 To 2 Step -1
            If ws.Rows(count1).Hidden = True Then
                If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngDel = ws.Rows(count1)
                Else
                    Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, ws.Rows(count1))
                End If
            End If
        Next count1

    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Intersect(rngDel, rngDel.ListObject.DataBodyRange).Delete 'if row is hidden, delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

    End If
End Sub
```

This works better and faster than anything else I had tried or was suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You might be hiding many times.  This is better:

```
If InStr(1, celltxt, txtrmv1, vbTextCompare) > 0 Or _
   InStr(1, celltxt, txtrmv2, vbTextCompare) > 0 Or _
   InStr(1, celltxt, txtrmv3, vbTextCompare) > 0 Or _
   InStr(1, celltxt, txtkp, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
     .Range("E" & loopct).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

EDIT: This should be a SIGNIFICANT speedup - it hides 10 rows at a time:
  (added Next iRow also)

```
Option Explicit
Dim ws As Worksheet

Sub Sub1()
  Dim iRow&, Count1&, txtrmv1, txtrmv2$, txtrmv3$, txtkp$, celltxt$
  Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
  Count1 = 65000 ' ??
  txtrmv1 = "Drive"
  txtrmv2 = "Inactivity"
  txtrmv3 = "Halt"
  txtkp = "UF_"
  For iRow = 2 To Count1
    DoEvents
    Application.StatusBar = "Making Table " & iRow
    celltxt = ws.Range("E" & iRow).Value
    If InStr(1, celltxt, txtrmv1, vbTextCompare) > 0 Or _
       InStr(1, celltxt, txtrmv2, vbTextCompare) > 0 Or _
       InStr(1, celltxt, txtrmv3, vbTextCompare) > 0 Or _
       InStr(1, celltxt, txtkp, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
         Call hideSub(iRow) '
    End If
  Next iRow ' thank you, tannmann357
  Call hideSub(0) ' flush
End Sub

Sub hideSub(hideRow&) ' hides 10 rows at a time
  Static a1&(10), na1&
  Dim i1&, zRange As Range
  If hideRow = 0 Then ' finish;end;flush
    For i1 = 1 To na1
      ws.Rows(a1(i1)).Hidden = True
    Next i1
    na1 = 0
  Else ' store row in array a1
    na1 = na1 + 1
    a1(na1) = hideRow
    If na1 = 10 Then ' hide 10 rows
      Set zRange = Union( _
        Rows(a1(1)), Rows(a1(2)), Rows(a1(3)), Rows(a1(4)), Rows(a1(5)), _
        Rows(a1(6)), Rows(a1(7)), Rows(a1(8)), Rows(a1(9)), Rows(a1(10)))
'Debug.Print zRange.Address
      ' this works but the syntax seems strange -- help me out
      ws.Range(zRange.Address).Rows.Hidden = True
      na1 = 0
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

EDIT: for my benefit:

replace

```
  ' this works but the syntax seems strange -- help me out
  ws.Range(zRange.Address).Rows.Hidden = True
```

with

```
  ws.Range(zRange).Rows.Hidden = True
```

Comment: This is logically better, but is still _very_ slow. I'm running through 65,000 or more rows... Is there a way to check the whole range at once, or something like that?

Comment: I get a `424: Object Required` error on `ws.Rows(a1(i1)).Hidden = True`

Comment: Sorry about the "Next". It goes BEFORE the `Call hideSub(0)`. Maybe you can `Debug.Print i1, a1(i1)` to see what's going on. Also, be sure to RESET before re-running (because of static variables)!

Comment: Okay, after fixing the position of `next` I am now getting another `424` error on `ws.Range(zRange.Address).Rows.Hidden = True`

Comment: see above comment @dcromley

Comment: @tannman357 - You still need to `Debug.Print i1, a1(i1)`. In the Visual Basic Window, there is the RUN button, the BREAK button, and the RESET button. I don't know if there is a keyboard shortcut.